# HTML anchors works only in IE

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

I have an html page with 2 columns(menu and a content div). When i click on a menu button i load with jquery an html page in content div. The problem is that anchors from loaded html page not worked at chrome and firefox, but it works on IE.

i load html page with jquery like that.

```
 <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#rightcolumn").html('<object width="950" height="8000" data="getStarted.html">');
$(window).scrollTop(0);
  });
</script>
```

I put the anchors like that:

```
<a href="#open">Open.</a>
<a name="open"></a>
```

Comment: You're using objects as poorly-supported-iframes and are loading them with JavaScript?!

Comment: i tried to load data in iframe but anchors works again only in IE...